# How can I add custom claims to Access Token by Cognito User Pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to add custom claims to accessToken in Cognito. But not able to find any documentation for the same. Does anyone using the same ?

Comment: Refer https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-customize-access-tokens-in-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

Comment: Essentially, you need to configure a pre-token generation Lambda trigger for your user pool. This Lambda function will run before tokens are issued and allows you to customize claims.